# Visual Studio 2015 - Add New Item: "No items available for Templates"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, visual-studio-2015

The ADO.NET Model Templates are missing in my version of VS2015. I have tried installing the SQL Server data tools and re-installing the EF Tools as per suggestions found elsewhere but neither have helped. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Many thanks

Comment: Same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: 'fraid not: I have not had any suggestions form anyone either.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem in the following way

> got to the Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Right click on Visual Studio 2015 -> Modify -> (tick the feature "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" ) and Update

give it a try

Comment: No go I'm afraid - any other thoughts?

Comment: If you are working on a Class Library project make sure you have created it as "Class Library Project" and not as "Class Library Project (package)". That's because in VS 2015 there are 2 project templates called Class Library... the second one is not made to support EF models.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the *No items found* message when attempting to simply add a new class to my project, and managed to fix it using the steps provided by [this blog post by Kevin Wilson](http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/fix-visual-studio-when-templates-disappear-from-your-add-new-item-dialogue/)

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Remove (and backup) the following directories from your Visual
   Studio installation.

> VisualStudioInstallDir\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache
>   VisualStudioInstallDir\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache

3. Run command prompt as administrator, and navigate to the Visual Studio directory, e.g.

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7IDE

4. Run the following command to regenerate the item and project template caches

> devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates

5. Restart Visual Studio, and if everything's worked, your class & project templates should all be working normally again.